# Cronjob with php script to execute bash command

Tags: php, bash, cron

I have a cronjob that executes a this php script. The check for the httpStatus works fine. The Big problem is the execution of the bash command. (else) Is there something wrong?

```
<?php
    $url = "https://xxx";

  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  
  /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  
  /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  
  if($httpCode == 200) {
      /* Handle 200 here. */
      $output = "Status 200 OK";
  }
  else{
      $output = shell_exec('cd public_html/redmine/ && bundle exec ruby bin/rails server -b webrick -e production -d');
      
  }
  
  curl_close($handle);
  
  /* Handle $response here. */

echo($output);


  ?>
```

Comment: Cron runs from another directory (possibly root), so you need to change your cd to the absolute path

Comment: If I understand it right: The script will execute not at it‘s own place... It will execute at  the directory where the crontab is defined ? @aynber

Comment: Correct. If you've defined it in `crontab -e`, it will start in the user's directory, but if it's the master cron, then it won't be. It's always smart to use absolute paths when dealing with cron

Comment: Thank you now the cronjob workes perfectly (with absolut path)

Comment: An off-topic side note: You should definitely use `systemd` `.timer` units instead of cronjobs. They give you much more control and flexibility, security hardening options etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend changing to an absolute path on the `cd` command, something like:

`cd /home/my-user/public_htm/redmine ...`

When you run a PHP script, the relative path is from where the script was executed and not the location of the PHP file.

For example, if you are running `php ./public_html/my-cronjob.php` from inside of `/home/my-user`, the current working directory (CWD) would be `/home/my-user` instead of `/home/my-user/public_html`. Any `cd` command is executed relatively to your CWD.

The current working directory can be checked with [getcwd()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

You could achieve the same result by using `__DIR__` which gives you the directory of the PHP file.

```php
if($httpCode == 200) {
    /* Handle 200 here. */
    $output = "Status 200 OK";
} else {
    $serverDir = __DIR__ . "/public_html/redmine";
    $output = shell_exec("cd {$serverDir} && bundle exec ruby bin/rails server -b webrick -e production -d");  
}
```

Comment: Thank you this Explantation helped me very much :)

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help :)